# Entity Framework - Multiple tables referencing to one table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity

I came here with an Entity Framework problem which I'm struggling with for some time already. Let's describe it quickly. I have 2 models that are referencing to one model... and I don't really know how can I create the relationship with EF annotations.

First model:

```
public class ProcessedLog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Some other data

    public virtual LogLocation Location { get; set; }
}
```

Second model:

```
public class QueuedLog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Some other data

    public virtual LogLocation Location { get; set; }
}
```

And the model that I'm referencing to:

```
public class LogLocation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("QueuedLog")]
    public int QueuedLogId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProcessedLog")]
    public int ProcessedLogId { get; set; }

    // Some other data

    public virtual QueuedLog QueuedLog { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcessedLog ProcessedLog { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I've already tried to do something but it's not working properly. I'm getting an error:

> LogLocation_ProcessedLog_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'LogLocation_ProcessedLog_Source' in relationship 'LogLocation_ProcessedLog'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
>   LogLocation_QueuedLog_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'LogLocation_QueuedLog_Source' in relationship 'LogLocation_QueuedLog'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

It works only when I do typical one-to-one relationship - but this is not what i want.

Btw. this is my first post at StackOverflow so i would like to say hi to everyone! :) You're creating a great community, thanks for all your work!

**Edit**
The question is: how can i create these models and relationshiph so it would work like this:

I add new ProcessedLog to Db -> It adds a new LogLocation with ProcessedLogId equal to the related ProcessedLog and the QueuedLogId is NULL.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: "It works only when i do... But this one is not working for me" Why not? Be more specific. What error messages do you get?

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm still new in programming so my questions are also not so good as i don't understand everything that well :) I've edited the post and added the error and the final question that i would like to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Database wise I am not sure if this is a great solution... Though it does look like it will work for you.

It worked with EntityFramework 6.1.3 and SQL Server Express.

ProcessedLog.cs

```
public class ProcessedLog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Some other data

    public virtual LogLocation Location { get; set; }
}
```

QueuedLog.cs

```
public class QueuedLog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Some other data

    public virtual LogLocation Location { get; set; }
}
```

LogLocation.cs

```
public class LogLocation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Some other data

    public virtual QueuedLog QueuedLog { get; set; }
    public virtual ProcessedLog ProcessedLog { get; set; }
}
```

Context.cs

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ProcessedLog> ProcessedLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QueuedLog> QueuedLogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LogLocation> LogLocations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProcessedLog>()
                    .HasRequired(p => p.Location)
                    .WithOptional(l => l.ProcessedLog);

        modelBuilder.Entity<QueuedLog>()
                    .HasRequired(p => p.Location)
                    .WithOptional(l => l.QueuedLog);
    }
}
```

Also the code I tested it with

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var processedLog = new ProcessedLog
    {
        Location = new LogLocation()
    };

    var queuedLog = new QueuedLog
    {
        Location = new LogLocation()
    };

    context.ProcessedLogs.Add(processedLog);
    context.QueuedLogs.Add(queuedLog);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to reply to your comment. Thanks a lot! :)